# Neo4j/SDN warining: No identity field found for class of type for exception class

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-boot, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

In my Neo4j/Spring Data Neo4j project I have a following exception class:

```
public class CriterionNotFoundException extends NotFoundDomainException {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2226285877530156902L;

    public CriterionNotFoundException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

}
```

During application startup I see a following WARN:

```
WARN  o.s.d.n.m.Neo4jPersistentProperty - No identity field found for class of type: com.example.domain.dao.decision.exception.DecisionAlreadyExistsException when creating persistent property for field: null
```

Why Neo4j/SDN is looking for identity field in this class ? How to correctly configure my application in order to skip this warning ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can ignore this warning- this is produced by SDN when building metadata Spring Data REST integration. It should not be doing this for Exceptions of course, and we'll have this fixed.

Comment: Currently SDN is creating a Warning for each and every class in the project on startup, even config files.

Comment: Hi Luanne, is it still the case? I'm getting the same warning. Thanks!

Comment: Warnings are not meant to be ignored; 2 years, and the warning is still spit out.

Answer (score 1):

One way "to correctly configure [your] application" would be add `EnableNeo4jRepositories` and `EntityScan` annotations to your `SpringBootApplication` (or your config bean) as mentioned [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/5.1.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#reference.getting_started.spring-configuration.boot) and specify the names of your packages with Neo4J relevant classes.

I've debugged the SDN/Neo4j code only for 5 minutes, so my guesses may be off, but, I believe those warnings are generated when you don't specify packages to scan for your entities, and repositories. I'm guessing in that case SpringBoot+Neo4J-mapping scans each and every class in your project, and if a class has some fields, but nothing resembling an "id" field, it spits this warning. (So adding a `Long id` field to the classes with warnings may be another (yes, very ugly) work-around as well)

I've seen those warnings vanished when I tried explicitly specifying package names in my project using SpringBoot 2.0.6 + spring-data-neo4j 5.0.11.